# Install Python modules on Shared hosting virtualenv

Tags: python, numpy

Experimenting with using python in a virtualenv on my shared hosting account. Based on [this dreamhost tutorial](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Flask) have installed pip and another module or two (echonest, remix), but trying to install numpy the long list of errors starts with `non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
/bin/sh: svnversion: command not found`.

The [virtualenv](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Python#Virtualenv) instructions I read say, "make sure that your path gives preference to ~/local/bin to /usr/bin so that your "local" copy of Python runs, and that your scripts refer to that location."

Does that suggest to make a link somewhere that points calls to `/usr/bin/` to `~/local/bin`?

Is the solution to find the install package and edit the paths in it's setup.py file?

Comment: Wanted to note that the tutorial I was following was using Passenger and a wsgi interface which I believe may have handled the paths and compiling that have prevented me from getting NumPy installed in the virtual ENV. He was using DreamHost.

Answer (score 1):

this is referring to the linux environment variable `$PATH` which lists the directories in which to look for executables for commands when you don't specify an absolute path. this will contain a list of comma separated paths eg:

```
/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

You just need to make sure that the `/usr/local...` stuff comes first (left) like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

Comment: you mean that I would run the command `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin`?

Comment: when I run the specific command above modules like `pip` and `easy_install` are no longer accessible. You probably didn't mean that specific path anyway. the path in the far left of my $PATH variable is the path to the virtualenv directory. That's good, right? It is `/home/mzoo7301/env/bin`. The packages i have been able to install are located in `/home/mzoo7301/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages`. Can I install numpy there somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're running `~/local/bin/python` when running setup.py?

One virtualenv-specific thing you can do is `source ~/local/bin/activate`, which automatically sets your virtualenv to take preference over everything else in your path.  It only works until you log out of your terminal instance or run `deactivate`

Comment: Well, I was doing `source bin/activate`. When I try `source ~/local/bin/activate` I get no such file or directory. Also wondering, is virtualenv something that will only run when activated, making it unworkable for a production app?

Comment: (My bad for not getting back to you sooner)  When you create a virtualenv, the ```bin/activate``` script is there from the get-go.  Are you sure ```~/local``` is your virtualenv, and that it has a bin directory? As far as production goes, you'll be okay as long as you use your virtualenv's commands.  The app will recognize ```~/local/bin``` as part of your path, since the initiating command  is run from that same directory.

Comment: thanks, man. if I cd to `~/`, it takes me to my home directory (shared hosting), in which the `virtualenv` resides. There's a `bin` folder in both places, but `local` in neither. Would making a `local` folder in the `virtualenv` and putting `bin` in it and adding that to the $PATH be in the right direction?

Comment: The ```~/local``` name is just what your tutorial recommended.  The virtualenv can be called anything.  In this case, you could ```cd ~```, and then ```virtualenv local```, local here being the name of a new directory.  But, it can be placed in any directory under any name

Comment: Oh okay. Then I have been running `source bin/activate` in the virtualenv directory (env, in this case). But numpy is looking for gfortran, gcc or some compiler it can have access to - and not finding one. `RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program`

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing confusion in the comments--- between "local" and "your virtualenv". And there is a parallel problem with $PATH. Is there just one path issue? No... there are *two*.

True, my own analogous efforts on a different shared-hosting account are ultimately crashing too, but I'm further along and I appear to have some things figured out. The confusion here partly comes about because there are two Dreamhost tutorials that are linked to in the question, but the authors of those two wiki chapters didn't make any effort to integrate the two.

And in the [second tutorial on Python](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Python#Virtualenv) the mistake is made of introducing the discussion of the local directory in the virtualenv section though it's only really explained in the next section on building your own Python. And the discussion on building your own isn't complete regarding what to do about $PATH. You don't need to build your own Python or have a local directory just to use virtualenv.

It may even be detrimental. The language at [this official virtualenv page](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html#using-virtualenv-without-bin-python) should fill you with despair, as it shows no effort at clarity. I think that it means that mod_python and mod_wsgi, either of which you must be using for your Flask experiment, don't use any Python that you might come up with--- they use their own Python interpreter, the system's version. But virtualenv, the program, also puts a Python interpreter inside your virtual environment (the interpreter that you will use to do installs and also ultimately to run flask if you let it). The point of the warning from the virtualenv folks is that you can't run with two different interpreters in the same server process. They show you the workaround.

But I have digressed. The second, Python tutorial instructs about building your own local Python, in the directory /home/yourusername/local. A more complete, yet succinct discussion is to be found at [Sugath Mudali's Blog](http://smudali.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/how-to-install-python-2-6-locally/).

Your virtualenv should occupy a *second* directory, which I'll call yourvirtenv. Alongside ~/local should be OK.

So, per Sugath Mudali's helpful instructions, you need to execute export PATH=/home/yourusername/local/bin:$PATH, which puts /home/yourusername/local/bin at the front of your $PATH, which you can confirm with "echo $PATH". Once you've done that, whenever you use "python" in your shell you'll be using the Python that you just installed, whose path you just put first.

Having done that, if you then cd into to your virtualenv source folder (somewhere in /home/youruserhame) and run "python virtualenv.py /home/youruserhame/yourvirtenv" it will create a directory ~/yourvirtenv, into which it will put a copy of the interpreter of your local Python. Generally it will not only be a distinct copy but it will differ even as to version from that of your system, which is at /usr/bin/ as /usr/bin/python ("usr" here is not you but is the oddly-named directory of the entire shared Linux machine to which no unprivileged user such as you has access, into which program binaries can be installed, by the privileged, for system-wide use).

Note that the Dreamhost Python wiki says "DreamHost has begun upgrading servers to Python 2.6.6 as of February 2012." Version 2.6 is adequate for virtualenv and practically everything else. So I would question the need to build your own Python in your case. (Note that Dreamhost even suggests that you should try to forget about it entirely.)

Anyway, on to the second PATH deal, as  limasxgoesto0  noted, once you run virtualenv.py and have thus created myvirtenv, if you're still in the /home/myusername user-root directory you run source myvirtenv/bin/source. That puts /home/myusername/myvirtenv/bin at the front of the path--- until you later simply run "deactivate" (no source in front of it). That is *all* that activate does.

Now, when you return days later and go back to work consider this: export PATH=/home/yourusername/local/bin:$PATH has evaporated. It's not permanent; goes away when the shell is closed. To make it permanent you have to add that statement to .bash_profile. Here's mine:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/myusername/local/lib
unset USERNAME
```

I found it necessary to reassert the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in order to make sqlite3 function, even though I had compiled sqlite3 and done that export prior to building Python.

Note that this .bash_profile invokes .bashrc. Depending on how Dreamhost has arranged things, you may have to put these exports in .bashrc.

Likewise, when you return to the shell myvirtenv will not be found to still be activated even if you never typed-in "deactivate". You only activate it temporarily in the shell to install stuff inside it and to start your server or run some other program that you've installed. Thereafter, the installed stuff knows to use the Python interpreter that has been copied to myvirtenv. To make that not happen, to make the stuff run off of the system Python interpreter you have to do what the aforementioned official virtualenv docs on mod_python, mod_wsgi say.

It looks as though this may be necessary even if you have not built your own Python, because otherwise you would have two Python interpreters running in the same server process. I am however sketchy on this. Flask is, like Django, a Python framework. An A2 Hosting tutorial--- they use Phusion Passerger too--- may be of interest. On their site search for "Django shared" and the tutorial will come up on top. Note that Chris C.'s instructions there tell you to use the --python=/path/to/python switch. In your case that could be /home/myusername/local/bin/python if you have locally installed Python, but in their case it's /usr/bin/python2.6. I think that their point is they don't want to get tech-support tickets from customers on problems caused by upgrades to their system python2.6 that could break your site. So that --python switch (-p directory is the short form; --python=directory is the long form) is to freeze the Python that your app will be using, to avoid such problems. It does so by copying all of the Python into your virtual environment, not just the interpreter.

I don't understand how they are avoiding the problem of mod_wsgi and the customer's apps using two different interpreters, but maybe that's what Phusion Passenger helps out with.

Comment: Thanks for your well written and extensive commentary, Mike. At the moment I have moved to a virtual server with WebHostingBuzz.com who are awesome - although looking at a $10/mo deal for 1gb ram with linode.com. I still want to pursue the virtualenv route, though. Were you actually able to access a compiler like GCC to compile packages on the shared server?

Comment: @Mike iLL Yes, strangely I had no problems whatsoever with the ./configure, make, make install sequence (with the prefix options). I would have thought it to be prohibited, but not so in my case (LMI.net, who are strangely off the air entirely this morning... a rare outage).

Comment: @Mike iLL Next I'm going to try this bit: http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#making-environments-relocatable. I would first do the very same local Python install on my desktop that I did on the shared hosting account. Then I'd use that install to create a virtualenv on my desktop and upload it to the shared hosting account (they do suggest that it may be possible to go from one Linux box to another). Wish me luck!